# Python tkinter app, ttk-heavy, pretty on MacOS, ugly on W10

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.6

I'm making a Python3 app with tkinter for GUI. I intend to make binaries for MacOS and Windows, and that was one of the reasons why I choose tkinter. I am using ttk for the widgets, and I was under the impression that that would automagically look great on all OSes.

But the colours are different. The distances to other widgets and borders are different. The button with a lot of text isn't wide enough. Frankly it just looks like crap on W10.

Is there some trick to getting it to look good on both of these two OSes, such as though certain styles?

[image: Pretty MacOS GUI]
[image: Ugly W10 GUI]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ttk widgets on each platform have their own default colors, margins, borders, fonts, etc. It is by design that they look different on different platforms.

Unfortunately, that means that you may have to add some platform-specific code from time to time to account for this. For example, you can add a little padding to the button, and you can manually set the color of the labels, or use geometry manager options to get them to fill the whole width of the screen with the same color.

Your goal is obtainable, but it will require a little more work to get it to look its best on all platforms.

Comment: I was hoping that I was missing some trick, but I guess I'll just have to put in the work. Thanks!